# Pandas DataFrame standards - nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am just starting to use Pandas for their DataFrames, but I had a question about what to do if a column entry for an observation is not a value but a dictionary of values? Example: three columns ('A', 'B', and 'C'), and entries are of the form (int, dictionary, string). Should you convert the dictionary to a Series or keep it as a dictionary?

I am not at a point yet to investigate further into Pandas and am unsure if it would be most beneficial ( or even just what a more seasoned Pandas user would do) to keep the values in column 'B' as dictionaries or another form. Also: these dictionaries all have a consistent form (i.e. 'B1': value, 'B2': value, etc.).

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It sort of depends on what you want to do with it, but I would argue that in most scenarios it would be more useful to change your dictionaries in column `B` to separate columns, as you say that they all have consistent forms. Consider the following:

```
A = [1,2]
B = [{'B1':123, 'B2':321}, {'B1':567, 'B2':891}]
C = ['string1', 'string2']
```

You can make a dataframe of these data using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B,'C':C})

>>> df
   A                       B        C
0  1  {'B1': 123, 'B2': 321}  string1
1  2  {'B1': 567, 'B2': 891}  string2
```

But that leaves the data in column `B` as a dictionary, and it's harder to access. I would first make a dataframe of your data in `B`:

```
df_B = pd.DataFrame(B)

>>> df_B
    B1   B2
0  123  321
1  567  891
```

And then concatenate it with a dataframe of your `A` and `C` data:

```
df_AC = pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'C':C}

final_df = pd.concat([df_AC, df_B], axis=1)

>>> final_df
   A        C   B1   B2
0  1  string1  123  321
1  2  string2  567  891
```

Leaving all your data easily accessible to `pandas`

Comment: I was thinking something like this would be the better method but was unsure of what would be most beneficial. I will definitely try this out- thanks! As a somewhat secondary question, is there any way in Pandas to 'group' columns? Suh as you could access B1 as df.B.1 instead of df.B1? or would you just have to make sure to name it in a way that symbolizes a grouping (B1, B2)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you could rename the columns to whatever you'd like in `df_B` after you create it using something like `df_B.columns=['my_name_one', 'my_name_two']` before you concatenate them